# Java RX's Flux.merge and switchIfEmpty

Tags: project-reactor, flux

I am trying to understand how JavaRx's Flux.merge and switchIfEmpty work together in regards to the below code as I am a bit confused on results I am seeing which is no doubt the result of my not fully grasping Java RX.

My question is ... If the call to wOneRepository... returns an empty list or the call to wTwoRepository... returns an empty list, will the switchIfEmpty code get executed?  Or will it only get executed if both calls return an empty list?

```
Flux<Widget> f1 = wOneRepository.findWidgets(email).onErrorResume(error -> Flux.empty());
Flux<Widget> f2 = wTwoRepository.findWidgets(email).onErrorResume(error -> Flux.empty());
return Flux.merge(f1, f2)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Widgets were not found")));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchIfEmpty()` will only be called if the upstream `Flux` completes without emitting anything, and that will only happen if both `f1` and `f2` complete without emitting anything. So, if both `findWidget` calls fail, or both return empty `Flux` instances, or some combination of those, then `switchIfEmpty` will be called. If either `f1` or `f2` emits a `Widget`, then that `Widget` will be emitted from the `merge` operator, which means `switchIfEmpty` will not be called.